# ejecutar comando winsat desde php en windows

Tags: php, javascript, java, windows

estoy tratando desde PHP de recuperar la memoria RAM usada, o la carga de trabajo de mi CPU, me vale cualquier cosa. Pero lo estoy haciendo desde un script PHP.
En linux tengo ya uno que me funciona pero necesito otro para windows 10. Bueno he probado ha hacer esto:

```
$w = array(); 
//WINSAT  QUERY -V
exec('WINSAT MEM -XML "%userprofile%\Desktop\info"',      $w);
var_dump($w);
```

Lo que busco como comento es un comando que me devuelva la memoria RAM en uso o la carga de trabajo de la cpu,
y pueda recuperarla desde PHP.